# cant inherit size of UiView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, gradient

I created a class for custom cell and I want to add a gradient layer. The problem is that it is working fine when i hardcode size of new layer and doesn't work when I try to inherit from super view.

Here is my code:

```
class FirstCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let gradient: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.frame = view.bounds // This code is working: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 200)

        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        layer.colors = [UIColor.lightGray.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor]
        view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        return view
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(gradient)

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": gradient]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-15-[v0]-15-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": gradient]))

    }

}
```

can you help me understand why this code `layer.frame = view.bounds` is not working?

Comment: try adding view.setNeedsDisplay() view.layoutIfNeeded() in your code!

Comment: @nikdange_me i tried to add it after creating view variable and it doesn't help

Comment: have you added it before {layer.frame = view.bounds} code?

Comment: @nikdange_me yes .. both lines .. right after let view = UIView()

Comment: LayoutIfNeeded and setNeedsDisplay won't do nothing before you added the view as a subview in addSubview(gradient)

Comment: @Almazini why dint you use { layer.frame = view.layer.frame } instead of { layer.frame = view.bounds } ??

Comment: @nikdange_me i was trying both .. but non of them are working because at that point size of view is 0 0 0 0

Comment: Whoever downvoted please explain why

Comment: @Almazini are you still stuck in the problem? or any improvement?

Comment: @nikdange_me unfortunately yes. I was trying to move gradient block after applying constraints when uiview has sizes but it didn't help

Comment: ok.. i can try to help you .. if wish/could send your code to understand and work on! through github.etc...

Answer (score 0):

Your newly created view has no size! It has no constraints, intrinsicContentSize, no frame set, etc.

Then you take its zero size and set with it the layer's frame. You just put zero in there, it won't change with the view

Instead, you should create the layer in a function after your view has a valid size already !

Good luck

Comment: make sense. but i am defining size after creating view - in autolayout constraints. how should i refactor code

Comment: Try to find the correct place to move the layer creation into. Maybe in didMoveToWindow, or didLayout or something , I write from memory only, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by making a subclass of UIView (UIImageView in my case) and overriding the layoutSubviews()

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.frame = view.bounds

        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        layer.colors = [UIColor.lightGray.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor]
        view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
}
```

And of course change the type of `let gradient` and the view you return in that declaration.
Try this currently not able to test it.

Comment: This is a bad solution since it will add a sublayer at each layout

Answer (score 0):

here is correct way to add gradient:

```
class FirstCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        setupGradientLayer()
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



    let cellView: UIView = {

        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return view
    }()


    func setupViews() {

        addSubview(cellView)

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": cellView]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-15-[v0]-15-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": cellView]))

    }



    private func setupGradientLayer() {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds

        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.lightGray.cgColor]

        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)

        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

    }

}
```